# copying values from each object in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Problem: Given an array of objects, I want to copy each object to a new array by changing the name of its KEYS.

I am trying to convert this object:

```
  items: [
    {

      "A": "Q1234",
      "B": "W1234",
      "C": 19.9,
      "D": 2
    },
    {
      "A": "Q1234",
      "B": "W1234",
      "C": 19.9,
      "D": 2
    },
```

to this:

```
  items: [
    {
      "id": "Q1234",
      "power": "W1234",
      "health": 19.9,
      "mana": 2
    },
    {
      "id": "Q1234",
      "power": "W1234",
      "health": 19.9,
      "mana": 2
    },
```

I tried the following, but its not working:

```
let replaceAll = () => {
  request.responseText.replace('A','id')
  request.responseText.replace('B','power')
  request.responseText.replace('C','health')
  request.responseText.replace('D','mana')
}
```

`request.responseText` output:

```
{"id":941282,"items":[{"id":117991,"power":6.5000,"health":102351,"mana":6},{"id":118993,"power":2.5000,"health":103353,"mana":1},{"id":128464,"power":11.6400,"health":112825,"mana":1}]}"

const _myItens = JSON.parse(request.responseText)
```

Comment: Your input is invalid JSON.`items: [` Keys need to be enclosed in double-quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) the objects, and use [aliases](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names) to create variables with the new names, then you can reconstruct the objects using [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer):

```js
const items = [{"A":"Q1234","B":"W1234","C":19.9,"D":2},{"A":"Q1234","B":"W1234","C":19.9,"D":2}]

const result = items.map(({ A: id, B: power, C: health, D: mana }) => ({
  id,
  power,
  health,
  mana
}))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I spent the weekend trying to understand this! Thank u very much!u

Answer (score 0):

Once the input is fixed so you can parse the JSON, create a function that transforms the `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` keys of an object into `id`, `power`, etc keys, and `.map` every object over that function:

```js
const responseText = `{ "items": [
    {

      "A": "Q1234",
      "B": "W1234",
      "C": 19.9,
      "D": 2
    },
    {
      "A": "Q1234",
      "B": "W1234",
      "C": 19.9,
      "D": 2
    }]}`;
const input = JSON.parse(responseText);
const keyMap = {
  A: 'id',
  B: 'power',
  C: 'health',
  D: 'mana'
};
const transform = shortObj => Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(shortObj).map(([key, val]) => [keyMap[key], val])
);
console.log(input.items.map(transform));
```

Comment: Thanks for the demo! i really appreciate!